# Smoothing a cusp in plotted data

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, smoothing

Here are my data points:

```
59.51 -59.3642
58.9944 -58.8079
58.4836 -58.2471
57.9778 -57.6819
57.4769 -57.1122
56.981 -56.5383
56.4901 -55.96
56.0043 -55.3775
55.5236 -54.7907
55.048 -54.1998
54.5777 -53.6048
54.1125 -53.0056
53.6525 -52.4025
53.1979 -51.7953
52.7486 -51.1842
52.3046 -50.5692
51.866 -49.9503
51.4328 -49.3277
51.0051 -48.7013
50.5828 -48.0712
50.4206 -47.8259
50.0013 -48.2641
49.5782 -48.6986
49.1514 -49.1294
48.7208 -49.5564
48.2865 -49.9797
47.8485 -50.3992
47.4069 -50.8148
46.9616 -51.2266
46.5128 -51.6344
46.0604 -52.0384
45.6046 -52.4383
45.1452 -52.8343
44.6824 -53.2263
44.2163 -53.6141
43.7467 -53.998
43.2738 -54.3777
42.7977 -54.7532
42.3182 -55.1246
41.8356 -55.4918
41.3497 -55.8548
40.8607 -56.2135
40.3686 -56.5679
39.8734 -56.918
39.3752 -57.2638
38.874 -57.6053
38.3698 -57.9423
37.8627 -58.2749
37.3528 -58.6031
36.8399 -58.9269
36.3243 -59.2461
35.8059 -59.5608
35.2848 -59.871
34.761 -60.1767
34.2345 -60.4777
33.7055 -60.7741
33.1738 -61.066
32.6397 -61.3531
32.103 -61.6356
31.5639 -61.9134
31.0224 -62.1865
30.4786 -62.4549
29.9324 -62.7185
29.384 -62.9773
28.8333 -63.2313
28.2804 -63.4805
27.7253 -63.7249
27.1682 -63.9644
26.609 -64.1991
26.0477 -64.4288
25.4845 -64.6537
24.9193 -64.8736
24.3522 -65.0886
23.7833 -65.2986
23.2126 -65.5037
22.6401 -65.7037
22.0658 -65.8988
21.4899 -66.0889
20.9124 -66.2739
20.3333 -66.4538
19.7526 -66.6288
19.1704 -66.7986
18.5867 -66.9633
18.0017 -67.123
17.4152 -67.2775
16.8275 -67.4269
16.2384 -67.5712
15.6481 -67.7103
15.0567 -67.8443
14.464 -67.9731
13.8703 -68.0968
13.2755 -68.2152
12.6798 -68.3285
12.083 -68.4365
11.4853 -68.5393
10.8868 -68.637
10.2874 -68.7294
9.68725 -68.8165
9.08635 -68.8984
8.48476 -68.9751
```

I plotted these point in Mathematica.

[image]

The plot shows a cusp. I would like to modify the plot to round off the cusp.

[image]

How can I do this in Mathematica?

Comment: In order to recreate the graphics you present, I had to add commas, curly brackets, and partition the data since it seems to be presented as `{x1, y1, x2, y2, ...}`. You should edit the post and format the data so that it is a valid _Mathematica_ list that will plot correctly without having to edit it.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of a data in CSV/TSV/table form, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 10):

The data in *Mathematica* format is

```
data = {{59.51,-59.3642},{58.9944,-58.8079},{58.4836,-58.2471},{57.9778,-57.6819},{57.4769,-57.1122},
{56.981,-56.5383},{56.4901,-55.96},{56.0043,-55.3775},{55.5236,-54.7907},{55.048,-54.1998},
{54.5777,-53.6048},{54.1125,-53.0056},{53.6525,-52.4025},{53.1979,-51.7953},{52.7486,-51.1842},
{52.3046,-50.5692},{51.866,-49.9503},{51.4328,-49.3277},{51.0051,-48.7013},{50.5828,-48.0712},
{50.4206,-47.8259},{50.0013,-48.2641},{49.5782,-48.6986},{49.1514,-49.1294},{48.7208,-49.5564},
{48.2865,-49.9797},{47.8485,-50.3992},{47.4069,-50.8148},{46.9616,-51.2266},{46.5128,-51.6344},
{46.0604,-52.0384},{45.6046,-52.4383},{45.1452,-52.8343},{44.6824,-53.2263},{44.2163,-53.6141},
{43.7467,-53.998},{43.2738,-54.3777},{42.7977,-54.7532},{42.3182,-55.1246},{41.8356,-55.4918},
{41.3497,-55.8548},{40.8607,-56.2135},{40.3686,-56.5679},{39.8734,-56.918},{39.3752,-57.2638},
{38.874,-57.6053},{38.3698,-57.9423},{37.8627,-58.2749},{37.3528,-58.6031},{36.8399,-58.9269},
{36.3243,-59.2461},{35.8059,-59.5608},{35.2848,-59.871},{34.761,-60.1767},{34.2345,-60.4777},
{33.7055,-60.7741},{33.1738,-61.066},{32.6397,-61.3531},{32.103,-61.6356},{31.5639,-61.9134},
{31.0224,-62.1865},{30.4786,-62.4549},{29.9324,-62.7185},{29.384,-62.9773},{28.8333,-63.2313},
{28.2804,-63.4805},{27.7253,-63.7249},{27.1682,-63.9644},{26.609,-64.1991},{26.0477,-64.4288},
{25.4845,-64.6537},{24.9193,-64.8736},{24.3522,-65.0886},{23.7833,-65.2986},{23.2126,-65.5037},
{22.6401,-65.7037},{22.0658,-65.8988},{21.4899,-66.0889},{20.9124,-66.2739},{20.3333,-66.4538},
{19.7526,-66.6288},{19.1704,-66.7986},{18.5867,-66.9633},{18.0017,-67.123},{17.4152,-67.2775},
{16.8275,-67.4269},{16.2384,-67.5712},{15.6481,-67.7103},{15.0567,-67.8443},{14.464,-67.9731},
{13.8703,-68.0968},{13.2755,-68.2152},{12.6798,-68.3285},{12.083,-68.4365},{11.4853,-68.5393},
{10.8868,-68.637},{10.2874,-68.7294},{9.68725,-68.8165},{9.08635,-68.8984},{8.48476,-68.9751}}

ListPlot[data]
```

[image: plot1]

Find the peak:

```
peak = MaximalBy[data, Last]
```

> {{50.4206, -47.8259}}

Find the position of the peak in the list:

```
peakpos = Position[data, peak[[1]]][[1,1]]
```

> 21

Set a width for the smoothing:

```
width = 5
```

We can try a quadratic smoothing:

```
quadratic = a x^2 + b x + c

quadRules = FindFit[Take[data, {peakpos - width, peakpos + width}], quadratic, {a, b, c}, x]
```

> {a -> -0.54444, b -> 54.6503, c -> -1419.69}

Replace the original data points with the smoothed points:

```
newdata = ReplacePart[data, i_ /; peakpos - width <= i <= peakpos + width :> {data[[i, 1]],
  quadratic /. quadRules /. x -> data[[i, 1]]}]
```

Plot it:

```
ListPlot[newdata]
```

[image]

Zoom:

```
ListPlot[newdata, PlotRange -> {{40, 60}, {-60, -30}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Anyway, I also need your little help again. How to programming in order to know some position from my data point which has value y = 0?

Answer (score 4):

Using the data from the other case, set the data to `dat`,

[image]

Now chop off the cusp.

```
datnocusp = Select[dat, (# // Last) < -5.5 &]
```

Plot this

[image]

Interpolate `datnocusp` and plot it.

```
ffnocusp = Interpolation[datnocusp];

Plot[ffnocusp[x], {x, dat // First // First, dat // Last // First}]
```

[image]

Plot with the original data.

```
Show[
     ListPlot[dat, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Red], 
     Plot[ffnocusp[x], {x, dat // First // First, dat // Last // First}]
    ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. Anyway do you know How to make programming in order to know some position from my data point which has value y = 0?

Comment: Are you looking for the cusp? The peak point? Or where it actually is zero? Does it have to be exactly zero?