# How to make logic for detecting "abnormality point" and remove it from data points

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, smoothing

Here are my data points:

```
{{86.0365, 38.6844}, {86.0526, 38.6998}, {86.069, 38.7154}, {86.085, 
  38.7308}, {86.1087, 38.7534}, {86.1332, 38.7766}, {86.1491, 
  38.7918}, {86.1651, 38.8068}, {86.1976, 38.8378}, {86.2377, 
  38.8758}, {86.2779, 38.9136}, {86.2942, 38.9289}, {86.3347, 
  38.9672}, {86.359, 38.99}, {86.3834, 39.0129}, {86.3996, 
  39.0281}, {86.4157, 39.0432}, {86.432, 39.0585}, {86.4562, 
  39.0812}, {86.4723, 39.0963}, {86.4968, 39.1191}, {86.5211, 
  39.1418}, {86.5534, 39.1719}, {86.5781, 39.1947}, {86.6104, 
  39.2249}, {86.6347, 39.2472}, {86.668, 39.278}, {86.6841, 
  39.2931}, {86.7082, 39.3152}, {86.7248, 39.3306}, {86.741, 
  39.3455}, {86.7573, 39.3605}, {86.7736, 39.3756}, {86.7898, 
  39.3904}, {86.8066, 39.4058}, {86.8229, 39.4209}, {86.839, 
  39.4357}, {86.8554, 39.4506}, {86.872, 39.4658}, {86.8965, 
  39.4882}, {86.9126, 39.503}, {86.9294, 39.5183}, {86.9456, 
  39.5332}, {86.962, 39.5481}, {86.9784, 39.5631}, {86.9945, 
  39.5776}, {87.012, 39.5936}, {87.0259, 39.6062}, {87.0506, 
  39.6289}, {87.0446, 39.6248}, {86.9309, 39.6007}, {86.9319, 
  39.6008}, {87.1508, 39.7224}, {87.3654, 39.9241}, {87.5335, 
  40.0905}, {87.7128, 40.2768}, {87.884, 40.4632}, {88.0522, 
  40.6547}, {88.2157, 40.8498}, {88.3747, 41.0487}, {88.5293, 
  41.2511}, {88.6793, 41.4572}, {88.8248, 41.6666}, {88.9656, 
  41.8794}, {89.1018, 42.0955}, {89.2334, 42.3148}, {89.3602, 
  42.5372}, {89.4823, 42.7625}, {89.5998, 42.9908}, {89.7124, 
  43.2221}, {89.8204, 43.4563}, {89.9238, 43.6932}, {90.0224, 
  43.933}, {90.1166, 44.1757}, {90.2062, 44.4212}, {90.2914, 
  44.6696}, {90.3721, 44.9211}, {90.4486, 45.1757}, {90.5209, 
  45.4338}, {90.589, 45.6955}, {90.6533, 45.9612}, {90.7138, 
  46.2312}, {90.7706, 46.5062}, {90.8241, 46.7866}, {90.8742, 
  47.0734}, {90.9214, 47.3672}, {90.9658, 47.6697}, {91.0078, 
  47.9819}, {91.0476, 48.3054}, {91.0858, 48.6428}, {91.1226, 
  48.9961}, {91.1587, 49.3684}, {91.1948, 49.7634}, {91.2319, 
  50.1849}, {91.2709, 50.6391}, {91.3132, 51.1306}, {91.3612, 
  51.6697}, {91.4166, 52.2603}, {91.4833, 52.9137}, {91.5656, 
  53.6424}, {91.6703, 54.4657}, {91.7964, 55.3387}, {92.0805, 
  56.9426}, {92.525, 58.792}, {93.1174, 60.7094}, {93.799, 
  62.5189}, {94.5706, 64.2644}, {95.4121, 65.9257}, {96.3133, 
  67.5056}, {97.2625, 69.0023}, {98.2484, 70.4143}, {99.2639, 
  71.7454}, {100.3, 72.9955}, {101.351, 74.1696}, {102.407, 
  75.2641}, {103.468, 76.2902}, {104.527, 77.2461}, {105.572, 
  78.1298}, {106.613, 78.9553}, {107.636, 79.7175}, {108.645, 
  80.4243}, {109.63, 81.0735}, {110.596, 81.673}, {111.538, 
  82.2233}, {112.45, 82.725}, {113.345, 83.1891}, {114.208, 
  83.61}, {115.042, 83.9921}, {115.847, 84.3391}, {116.627, 
  84.6545}, {117.378, 84.9388}, {118.101, 85.1949}, {118.795, 
  85.4242}, {119.46, 85.6288}, {120.101, 85.8117}, {120.716, 
  85.9736}, {121.305, 86.1165}, {121.872, 86.2421}, {122.412, 
  86.3509}, {122.933, 86.4453}, {123.434, 86.5265}, {123.913, 
  86.5948}, {124.377, 86.6522}, {124.822, 86.6988}, {125.254, 
  86.736}, {125.677, 86.7646}, {126.082, 86.7846}, {126.475, 
  86.7968}, {126.87, 86.8018}, {127.251, 86.7998}, {127.625, 
  86.7909}, {128.011, 86.7748}, {128.167, 86.7663}, {128.19, 
  86.7649}, {128.947, 86.7163}, {129.704, 86.6611}, {130.46, 
  86.5993}, {131.215, 86.5309}, {131.97, 86.4559}, {132.724, 
  86.3743}, {133.478, 86.2862}, {134.23, 86.1915}, {134.982, 
  86.0902}, {135.733, 85.9823}, {136.483, 85.868}, {137.231, 
  85.747}, {137.979, 85.6196}, {138.726, 85.4856}, {139.471, 
  85.3451}, {140.215, 85.1981}, {140.958, 85.0447}, {141.7, 
  84.8847}, {142.44, 84.7183}, {143.178, 84.5454}, {143.915, 
  84.3661}, {144.651, 84.1804}, {145.384, 83.9883}, {146.116, 
  83.7897}, {146.847, 83.5848}, {147.575, 83.3735}, {148.302, 
  83.1559}, {149.027, 82.9319}, {149.749, 82.7016}, {150.47, 
  82.4651}, {151.189, 82.2222}, {151.905, 81.9731}, {152.619, 
  81.7177}, {153.331, 81.4561}, {154.041, 81.1884}, {154.748, 
  80.9144}, {155.453, 80.6343}, {156.156, 80.348}, {156.855, 
  80.0556}, {157.553, 79.7571}, {158.247, 79.4525}, {158.939, 
  79.1419}, {159.629, 78.8253}, {160.315, 78.5026}, {160.999, 
  78.174}, {161.68, 77.8394}, {162.357, 77.4989}, {163.032, 
  77.1525}, {163.704, 76.8003}, {164.373, 76.4421}, {165.038, 
  76.0782}, {165.7, 75.7084}, {166.359, 75.3329}, {167.015, 
  74.9517}, {167.668, 74.5647}, {168.317, 74.1721}, {168.962, 
  73.7738}, {169.604, 73.3699}, {170.243, 72.9604}, {170.877, 
  72.5454}, {171.509, 72.1248}, {172.136, 71.6988}, {172.76, 
  71.2672}, {173.38, 70.8303}, {173.996, 70.388}, {174.609, 
  69.9402}, {175.217, 69.4872}, {175.821, 69.0289}, {176.422, 
  68.5653}, {177.018, 68.0965}, {177.61, 67.6225}, {178.198, 
  67.1434}, {178.782, 66.6592}, {179.362, 66.1698}, {179.937, 
  65.6755}, {180.508, 65.1761}, {181.074, 64.6718}, {181.637, 
  64.1625}, {182.194, 63.6484}, {182.747, 63.1294}, {183.296, 
  62.6056}, {183.84, 62.0771}, {184.38, 61.5438}, {184.914, 
  61.0058}, {185.444, 60.4632}, {185.97, 59.916}, {186.49, 
  59.3642}, {187.006, 58.8079}, {187.516, 58.2471}, {188.022, 
  57.6819}, {188.523, 57.1122}, {189.019, 56.5383}, {189.51, 
  55.96}, {189.996, 55.3775}, {190.476, 54.7907}, {190.952, 
  54.1998}, {191.422, 53.6048}, {191.888, 53.0056}, {192.347, 
  52.4025}, {192.802, 51.7953}, {193.251, 51.1842}}
```

I plotted these point in Mathematica.

[image]

And after checked and zoom in, I get "abnormality point"as shown below

[image]

How to make logic (loop) for detecting this"abnormality point" and remove it from data points? so that the curve will be smooth.

Comment: This and your other question (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147446/smoothing-a-cusp-in-plotted-data) seem to request competely data-driven solutions with no subject matter considerations.  Are there at least guesses as to why the data has these "oddities"?  As noted below the x-values are not in sorted order and there are two points with nearly the same x and y values associated with the oddity.  Is this some explainable instrument hiccup?

Comment: @JimBaldwin  I don't know why it happened. And that's the reason why I try to detect and remove it using programming.

Answer (score 3):

This is somewhat too ad-hoc, but works in this case:

```
data = {data points in the question}

Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/QuantileRegression.m"]

qfunc = QuantileRegression[data, 40, {0.5}][[1]];

outlierPoints = 
  Select[data, Abs[#[[2]] - qfunc[#[[1]]]] > (0.001 #[[2]]) &];
outlierPoints // Length
(* 55 *)

Show[
 ListLinePlot[{data, {#, qfunc[#]} & /@ data[[All, 1]]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{85, 88}, {38, 40}}],
 ListPlot[outlierPoints, PlotStyle -> Red]
 ]
```

[image]

It is probably a good idea to see other discussions about outlier detection and Quantile regression at MSE.

Answer (score 1):

`Listplot` is abnormal because `x` values of your `data` are not fully in ascending order.

To restore ascending order, you can remove all elements which have negative difference of the `x` component compared to the previous element.
You may need to repeat this removing procedure until all differences for all elements are positive:

```
removeNegDiffElements[data_?MatrixQ] := Pick[data, 
    Join[{1}, Sign@Differences@First@Transpose@data], 1];
removeAllNegDiffElements[data_?MatrixQ] := FixedPoint[removeNegDiffElements, data];
```

For your data:

```
ListPlot[{data, removeAllNegDiffElements[data]},
    PlotRange -> {{86.8, 87.4}, {39.2, 40}}, 
    Joined -> True, 
    Mesh -> Full]
```

[image: Plot without abnormality]

Comment: I've tried to apply your suggestion program (copy and paste) in my mathematica program but it is unsuccessful running. do you have any sugestion? because I am newbie in this field. Thank You

Comment: @SelfA Sorry, I have corrected a typo in the code. Before you evaluate the code you should also define `data = {all your data points here}`.

Comment: @SelfA I also forgot to add that line, `data = {all your data points here}`, in my post.

Comment: @Shadowray Thank you. It's work. By the way, I'am still thinking if any others case is as close as with this case but I want to remove all elements which have positive difference of the x component compared to the previous element. so, what should be modified for following your programming above?

Comment: You can change `Pick[data, Join[{1}, Sign@ Differences@ First@ Transpose@ data], 1]` to `Pick[data, Join[{-1},  Sign@ Differences@ First@ Transpose@ data], -1]`.

Comment: @Shadowray Thanks so much. I am very new comer in this program. Could you please explain to me the "step by step of your solution above"?. Because it looks like for advance level ^_^. If the illustration needed, could  you please sent to selfa47@mail.com ?

Answer (score 1):

I want to ensure I have a robust solution, so I will use the data below which has several outliers.

```
data = Join[Array[0.01 # {Cos@#, Sin@#} &, 400, {0.0, 8.0 Pi}], 
  Array[{0.5025, 0.003} - 0.01 # {Cos@#, Sin@#} &, 400, {8.0 Pi, 0.0}]
];
Part[data, 33] = {-0.0041, 0.04};
Part[data, 128] = {-0.024, 0.11};
Part[data, 225] = {0.0, 0.18};
Part[data, 326] = {0.05, 0.22};
Part[data, 352] = {-0.33, -0.03};
Part[data, 366] = {-0.25, -0.23};
Part[data, 375] = {0.0, -0.35};
Part[data, 450] = {0.85, 0.01};
Part[data, 475] = {0.4, -0.24};
Part[data, 574] = {0.58, -0.145};
Part[data, 673] = {0.5, -0.099};
ListLinePlot[data, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Axes -> None]
```

[image: original data]

Next, I determine which samples have sharp corners. The symbol sharpCorners below is 1 when the respective sample is a sharp corner, and 0 when the respective sample is not a sharp corner. I also determine the samples at positions 325, 475, 573 have two adjacent sharp corners due to one outlier.

```
directionList = ArcTan @@@ Differences@data;
sharpCorners = Unitize@Clip[Abs@Differences@directionList, 
   {Pi*5/6, Pi*7/6}, {0, 0}];
   twinSharpCornerPositions = 1 + Flatten@Position[Partition[sharpCorners,
   2, 1], {1, 1}]
(*{325,475,573}*)
```

Below, samples 475 and 476 are Red and Green respectively. I also define a function 'pickOutlierPositions' to determine which of adjacent samples that both have a sharp corner.

```
ListLinePlot[data, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.4, 0.638}, {-0.25, -0.16}}, Axes -> None, 
  Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize@5, Point@data, Red, 
  Point@Part[data, 475], Green, Point@Part[data, 476]}
]
```

[image: Cose-up on samples]

```
pickOutlierPositions = 
   Compile[{{data, _Real,2}, {twinSharpCornerPositions, _Integer,1}},
   Module[{x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4}, 
   Table[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, {x4, y4}} = 
   Take[data, {posn - 1, posn + 2}];
   With[{d23Squared = (x3 - x2)^2 + (y3 - y2)^2},
     If[Max[d23Squared, (x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2] > 
        Max[d23Squared, (x4 - x3)^2 + (y4 - y3)^2],
        posn,(* else *)posn + 1
     ]
  ], {posn, twinSharpCornerPositions}]
]];

signleSharpCornerPositions = 
  Complement[1 + Flatten@Position[sharpCorners, 1], 
  twinSharpCornerPositions, 1 + twinSharpCornerPositions];
outlierPositions = Join[signleSharpCornerPositions, 
   pickOutlierPositions[data, twinSharpCornerPositions]
]
(*{33,128,225,352,366,375,450,673,326,475,574}*)
```

Above, I found the samples at positions 325, 475, 573 have sharp corners, and are also adjacent to samples with sharp corners. The output above says samples 326, 475, 574 are outliers. Next, I remove the samples that are outliers by replacing them with the expression Sequence[]. After the outliers are removed, the curve is smooth.

```
Part[data, outlierPositions] = Sequence[];
ListLinePlot[data, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Axes -> None]
```

[image: smoothed data]